# Ethernet Switch configuration mode

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, switches, ethernet, phy

I'm trying to understand the [Ethernet Switch](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/KSZ9893#:%7E:text=The%20KSZ9893%20is%20a%20fully,as%20RGMII%2C%20MII%20or%20RMII.) product.

On page 54,55, we can see that, the MAC signals, Like for MII and RMII interface, we can understand that the digital MAC port 3, can be configured as either in MAC mode or PHY mode.

But for RGMII interface, there are no 2 separate tables where we can configure as either in MAC or PHY mode?

Why is that?

Comment: Does it matter why?

Comment: I'm unable to understand. Like, for MII and RMII interfaces, the switch has the ability to act in either the PHY mode or MAC mode, but for RGMII interface, why does the switch not have the ability to be in either PHY mode or MAC mode?

Comment: We can see 2 tables for each interface. Table 4-27 & 4-28 which tells that for the MII interface, the port 3 can be configured as either a PHY or a MAC. Table 4-30 & Table 4-31 tells that for the RMII interface, the port 3 can be configured as either a PHY or a MAC. But we don't see any such tables for RGMII interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on page 44:

> #### 4.5.2 MAC INTERFACE CLOCKS
>
> The MII interface is clocked asymmetrically, with the PHY device driving both the RX_CLKx receive clock and the TX_- CLKx transmit clock to the MAC device (...)
>
> The RMII interface uses a single 50MHz clock. This REFCLK may be sourced either from the KSZ9893R or from the connected device (...)
>
> The RGMII interface employs source synchronous clocking, so it is symmetrical and does not require a mode selection. An output clock is generated on the RX_CLK pin, while an input clock is received on the TX_CLK pin (...)

It's all related to who provides the clock(s). In MII or RMII mode one of the two devices provides the single clock used for both TX and RX, so you need to pick which one. In RGMII there's one clock for each direction, so you don't have to device who is providing the clock.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you just expand a little more on what is the meaning of asymmetrical clocking and symmetrical clocking?

Comment: MII: PHY sends clocks, so you have to device who is PHY. RMII. One of the two sends single clock, so you have to device who. RGMII: each device sends the clock matching the data signals. So you can swap them around as much as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In that case, I've connected 2 switches in back to back fashion. The port 3 of switch 1, is connected to port 3 or switch 2. In that case, which switch will take as PHY mode and which will be MAC mode?

Comment: Neither, there's no difference between PHY and MAC modes when using RGMII, the interface is symmetrical.

Comment: No, I'm asking in case of MII and RMII interface, which would be PHY and which would be MAC?

Comment: @Newbie just set one to PHY and the other to MAC. It’s just a matter of selecting which one sends the clock used for both directions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135815/discussion-between-newbie-and-jcaron).